# Formula to calculate grade using selected best questions answered

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Data below shows the maximum score for every question in an exam, and the score of a student. What excel formula can I use to calculate student score using his best 7 questions answered?

```
Question    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9     Total
Marks      10   15  10  5   15  10  10  15  10    100
```

**Student score**

```
John D      0   6.5  4  0   3   0   7   2   5     27.5
```

Comment: Use the [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) for a *k* of 1 to 7.

Comment: Thanks Tim...but i need to weight the final score over 100%, taking into account the maximum score of the selected questions.

Comment: If John's score for question 1 was 6, is that a better score than his score of 6.5 for question 2?

Comment: Yes. If he scored 6 over 10 for question 1. It counts as better score than 6.5 over 15 for question 2.

Comment: You obviously do not know what you actually want. The sample data shows expected results that are wrong (according to your comments). Even the new description taken from comments below is ambiguous since there is a 67% chance of returning 34.3 and a 33% chance of returning 32.3. 0/5 is no better or worse than 0/10 but which you pick will affect the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come up with something that should almost fulfill your requirement.

Solution can be broken down into following steps:

**1.** **Get the top 7 scoring answers** (*this is based on your comment where you mentioned that 6 out 10 is better than 6.5 out of 15*). As per the data provided in the question best performing score would be 7/10 followed by 5/10, 6.5/15, and so on.
Write the below formula in the `Cell B6` and drag/copy across till `H6` to get these values.

```
    =LARGE(($B$4:$J$4)/($B$2:$J$2),COLUMN(B1)-COLUMN($B$1:$H$1)+1)
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

**2.** Now we have top 7 scores in `Row 6`. On the basis of these values get their corresponding marks. For this enter the following formula in `Cell B7`

```
    =INDEX($B$2:$J$2,1,SMALL(IF((($B$4:$J$4)/($B$2:$J$2)=B6),COLUMN($B$1:$J$1)-COLUMN($B$1)+1),COUNTIF($B$6:B6,B6)))
```

and drag/copy across till `H7`.

Again this is an array formula.

**3.** After getting marks its time to get scores. Use below formula in `Cell B8`  and drag/copy across till `H8`

```
    =INDEX($B$4:$J$4,1,SMALL(IF((($B$4:$J$4)/($B$2:$J$2)=B6),COLUMN($B$1:$J$1)-COLUMN($B$1)+1),COUNTIF($B$6:B6,B6)))
```

This is an array formula too.

**4.** In `Cell K7` and `Cell K8` enter `=SUM(B7:H7)` and `=SUM(B8:H8)` respectively.

**5.** To get the percentage of the top 7 scoring questions with respect to marks allotted write `=K8/K7`.

[image]

**Drawback of this solution:**

When ever there is tie in values in the `Row 6` this may not give you desired result. By saying tie I do not mean same score (eg. 2/10, 2/15) instead I am talking about performance on each question like 2/10 and 3/15 both will give same result as far as performance is concerned.

In the sample data provided in the question John has three scores of 0's (one out of 10 and other two out of 15). Mathematically all three are same however if you want to include score of 0/10 in top 7 considering that it is better than 0/15, this may not happen. In case of tie the above formulas will get value in the order of occurrence i.e. if 0/15 appears before 0/10 then its 0/15 that will be considered in the formula and not 0/10. See the image for reference.

If you have any queries let me know.

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys for your assistance and time. Decided to do it manually. Resolved.